# How to make full 100% height of floated element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html markup:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.right {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
}
.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  <div class="left-container">
    <div class="left">
        Left fluid
        <br/>
        multiple rows
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see right block looks ugly. How could I make right element fluid height 100%?

Comment: This question has been asked several times. Have you checked the older ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the rule `height:100%` the right div, and remove `float:right`.  I changed it to `position:absolute`, so that you didn't need the container's height.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.right {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.left {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right:40px;
}
```

```html
<br><br><div class="container">
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  <div class="left-container">
    <div class="left">
        Left fluid
        multiple rows a really long sentence a really long sentence a really long sentence a really long sentence a really long sentence a really long sentence.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks got the reply. Is it possible to make without setting height of `.container`?

Comment: It sure is!  Use `position:absolute`, instead of `float:right`.  You can then add `right:0` and you won't need the `.container`'s height!  Check my edit . . .

Comment: I've tried this solution and it does't useful for me because when you set `position: absolute` to right block you drop it out of flow and green container overlaps it

Comment: For this, you need `position:absolute`.  You can fix your problem by setting the `margin:right` CSS property.  Now it doesn't overlap.  Check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If your application will run in a modern browser, then using flexbox is a good way to go: http://jsfiddle.net/2hn9zgog/.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right">Right</div>
    <div class="left">
        Left fluid
        <br/>multiple rows
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
}

.right {
    order: 2;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.left {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I can't use `flex` due it poor supporting of browsers

Answer (score 0):

add clear: both; after floated element.

```
<div class="right"></div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
html, body{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}

.your-container{
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: My mistake, try reading this:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403